# Factor Analysis - Rotation failed to converge in 25 iterations!

Tags: pca, spss, factor-analysis, factor-rotation

I am conducting a Factor Analysis using PCA.
I have used Oblique and Orthagonal Rotations and when I am trying to analyse my results I get the message:

**"Rotation failed to converge in 25 iterations"**

So I had to adjust this - sometimes I get the results using 29 and sometimes more than 50.

Is there an underlying problem with my results? As I have heard through tutorials on YouTube that it should not be more than 25 interactions!

Comment: It could be helpful to know what software you are using.

Comment: So what? Raise the upper bound for iterations. You can do it even in the dialog box. Beware Youtube tutorials. If you have problems with your data - I can't say. Are there other warnings being displayed? If you have extracted, maybe, too much factors, they will require more iterations to converge.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications @ttnphns. I am not getting any more errors.

Comment: It is not uncommon to need more than 25 iterations.  The default value should really be raised.